# How adding some values in join works?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, left-join

I have Following query

```
select a.id as 'as',b.id as 'b',a.student,b.student
from seat a 
left join seat b on a.id + case when a.id%2=0 then -1 else 1 end = b.id
```

which is giving me following output

[image]

can someone explain me how `join` condition is working?
why the value of `b.id` is changing ?

Comment: Take that case expression and add it to the column list of the query. That will more clearly let you see how it works.

Answer (score 0):

The `case` part in your query make this happen:

```
on a.id + case when a.id%2=0 then -1 else 1 end
```

for example when `a.id = 1` in the `on` clause it actually become `a.id + 1 = b.id`
because the `case` part will return `1` when `a.id = 1`
therefor for the row where `a.id = 1` it will try to join the row in b where `b.id = 2`

repeating this logic and you get that output.

---

for the `case` clause it spoke as following:

- when the id is plural return -1
- when the id is odd return 1

adding up the `a.id` you get:

- when the id is plural return the smaller adjacent odd number ( a.id - 1)
- when the id is odd return the bigger adjacent plural number ( a.id + 1)

so with `id = 1` you get `2` , with `id = 4` you get `3` vice versa.

Comment: Thanks you made it clear made. i was just curious how it works

Comment: @hamzakazmi thanks for the reply, but if the answer do help you solving the problem, consider accept the answer. There is no obligation to do this but this help the communities to improve. might also consider to do the same thing with your old post.

Answer (score 0):

It's a rather clever (and daft at the same time) method to join together every two adjacent rows (in `Id` order) to each other. It uses modulo 2 and a conditional to either join the row before or the row after. Why you would want to do this in the first place, I can't think at all.

This can be accomplished more efficiently by scanning the table just once and using window functions:

```sql
SELECT
    s.Id,
    s.Name,
    OtherId = CASE WHEN s.Id % 2 = 1 THEN s.NextId ELSE s.PrevId END,
    OtherName = CASE WHEN s.Id % 2 = 1 THEN s.NextName ELSE s.PrevName END,
FROM (
    SELECT
        s.Id,
        s.Name,
        NextId = LEAD(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id),
        PrevId = LAG(Id) OVER (ORDER BY Id),
        NextName = LEAD(Name) OVER (ORDER BY Id),
        PrevName = LAG(Name) OVER (ORDER BY Id),
    FROM Student s
) s
```